# How should i test if UART port is working?

Tags: serial-port, yocto, android-source, uart, tty

I wanted to test if my UART(`ttyMT1`) is working on my custom board (android project). I have 2 UARTs on my board-  `ttyMT0` &  `ttyMT1`. UART  `ttymt0` is my debug port. I have `microcom` on my board as well.

**`Test1:`**

I connected Tx and Rx of  `ttyMT1` with a female to female jumper wire. Then, on my ADB, i opened microcom for `ttyMT1` using the below command:

```
microcom -s 115200 /dev/ttyMT1
```

On my debug port (using minicom), `ttyMT0`, I transmitted to `ttyMT1` using echo as shown :

```
echo -ne 'Hello' > /dev/ttyMT1
```

and i was able to get the transmitted data print (HELLO) on `ttyMT1`.

**What i wanted to know was, is this enough to verify that my UART `ttyMT1` is working fine or do i need to try something else?**

**`Test2:`**

What i tried again was to connect `ttyMT0` to my PC's usb port and `ttyMT1` to another USB port of my PC using 2 separate USB to UART connectors. Then i opened 2 minicom, one for each and tried to transmit the same `Hello` from `ttyMT0` to `ttyMT1` (`ttyMT0` shows as `ttyUSB0` on my PC and `ttyMT1` as `ttyUSB1`). But i didn't receive any print on `ttyMT1`. Why is that?.

p.s. I'm unable to type anything on `ttyMT1`. I probed `ttyMT1` on Oscilloscope and i got the Tx signal but I didn't get anything on my scope when I probed on Rx.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have SELinux permission to access serial port in android. However check this code here to read serial port : https://programmer.help/blogs/serial-port-operation-with-jni-method-under-android.html. It will require you JNI.